# Looking for short, home routine for thighs and abs

Tags: workout-routines, abdominals, thigh

I have a personal trainer which I hit up once a week - love it. We do all our stuff outside with bascially nothing.

I'm trying to get a bit more stuff to do mid week which is only around 15-20 mins long. maybe once or twice a week.

I'm looking to work my thighs and work get some nice abs.

I fully understand that

- 10-15 mins 2x a week is way not enough.
- nutrition, nutrition, nutrition...

.. but with those aside, does anyone have some suggestions for a mid 30's guy, looking to do some extra stuff outside without having to buy any equipment and just using 'whats around'. A good example will be to assume i have access to a standard park next door to my house : some steps, few bolders and lots of grass.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a pull-up bar (or something else you can hang of)? Most parks do.

Comment: Are you looking for exercises to supplement your current routine or a full workout?

Comment: @VPeric - yeah, but it's pretty short so it might be awkward for me to use it.

Comment: @Christopher Bibbs - suppement. I don't think a full workout in 10-15 mins would work?

Comment: @Pure.Krome recent studies have shown that signifant benefits can be had from regular workouts as short as 10 minutes. Not significant strength or endurance, but quality and duration of life. I don't have a link to the paper handy, though.

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw in my recommendation of Tabata again: [What is tabata? How effective is it?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/what-is-tabata-how-effective-is-it)

Tabata is basically High Impact Intense Training - a series of 4 exercises done with a timer (20 seconds active then 10 seconds rest for each exercise 8 times).  You can focus on abs and legs with exercises like: burpees, body weight squats, lunges, etc.  The exercises are limitless and can includes light weights, sandbag, medicine ball, etc.  Here's a good site for a look into the type of exercises you can perform (and she seems to focus on the abs and butt a lot): http://www.bodyrock.tv/

Answer (score 2):

[Ab Ripper X](http://www.freeworkoutguides.com/workoutguides/p90x-ab-ripper-workout) is a 15 minute ab workout that's part of the [P90X](http://www.beachbody.com/product/fitness_programs/p90x) series. It consists of 11 moves, 25 reps each. You don't need any equipment for this.

[Joey Atlas's leg/thigh routine](http://legbutthipthighexercises.com/) takes about an hour, but can be broken up into three sections of 20 minutes each (standing routine and 2 floor routines). I think it's designed for women, so it might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's pretty challenging and you really only need stairs or a chair and a towel.

Answer (score 1):

As far as abs and thighs go, my favorite workout video is the Hip Hop Abs series featuring Shaun T. (He leads the Insanity workouts as well.) The [Hips, Buns, and Thighs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx6qUyYEnLo) video is a great, short workout that really does a good job targeting the areas as well as being fun. Shaun T is also a really great motivator, and the vids are just *fun*, which is so rare in a workout vid. I really recommend the whole HHA series, but this vid is most specific to your request.

Answer (score 0):

For  thighs you can do normal body weight squats, takes a few minutes, alternatively the kettle bell swing is a good exercise, and will work both thighs and abs, add some reverse crunches or rows and you're done.

Any exercise is better than none.