# Dynamic Strength/Jump Rope workout

Tags: workout-routines

Due to financial issues (who knew a 7-month-old would be so expensive :)), I'm going to be cancelling my gym membership in the next few weeks.  I do not have weights at home, and I'm hesitant to buy used ones.  Instead, I'm looking to go back to Harry Wong's Dynamic Strength exercises that I was doing about 6 years ago.  They were great, but I want to integrate a good jump-rope workout with it.

Does anyone have any advice on routines for either portion of the workout?

BTW - I will also be doing cardio training (non-jump-rope-related) to train for some 5k races coming up (that's the easy part)

Comment: I'd urge you to reconsider buying at least a few used weights. You can usually get them cheap and they really help round out a home routine. I've never had a dumbell break. Rust is about the only thing you might find on a used weight that won't be found on one at the store.

Comment: true, but also having heavy weights near a 7-month-old is not a great idea.  We're limited in space in my house

Comment: Though the risk of an infant lifting a 20lb weight is lower than you might think, I still understand your concern. :) I run new father workshops through the local hospital so I've heard this before. In fact, I'll be hearing it again tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Spark People has a 10-minute jump rope cardio routine that you can check out [here](http://www.sparkpeople.com/resource/fitness_articles.asp?id=1056). I've never done this one myself but I've done other Spark People cardio routines (see my answer to [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/what-can-i-do-for-cardio-while-i-am-on-vacation-with-no-equipment/3894#3894) for specifics) and they are pretty good workouts.

For the other portion of your workout, if you don't want to buy weights you might try some body weight exercises. [This post](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/86/what-are-some-short-30-minute-body-weight-lift-routines-for-travel) has a bunch of good recommendations, including [You Are Your Own Gym](http://marklauren.com/) and [CrossFit](http://www.crossfitflagstaff.com/CrossFitBodyweightWorkoutResourcev2.0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I've found Pavel Tsatsouline's book [The Naked Warrior](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0938045555) to be a good source of bodyweight exercises.

Comment: I read this a few years back...didn't find it to be what I was looking for.  That's how I discovered Wong's book.

Thanks, though.